# Why my ASP.NET MVC4 ActionLink Ajax code doesn't make an async request?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Why this code doesn't works properly? The link is shown but when I click on it the request is not asynchronously made. Instead  the browser made a normal request! :/ Notice: I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4!

Here's my CSHTML block code:

```
<div id="latestReviews"></div>

@Ajax.ActionLink("Click here to see the latest review", "LatestReviews", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions {
    UpdateTargetId =  "latestReviews",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
    HttpMethod = "GET"
})
```

And here's my Controller Action:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult LatestReviews(){
        var review = RestaurantReviewQueries.FindTheLatest(_db.Reviews, 1).Single();
        return PartialView("_Review", review);
    }
```

Comment: Please reword your title to reflect what you're asking.

Comment: `the request is not asynchronously made. Instead the browser made a normal request`. How do you know the call is not asyncronous? Does your full page refresh in the end? I'm not sure what you mean by `Instead the browser made a normal request`

Comment: Exactly! The page is entirely refreshed! "Normal request" = not async ahaha Instead of show the result in the div, the browser goes to another page and show the content

Comment: Not sure in this case: You have a div with id of `latestReviews` and  that is set to be the UpdateTargetId as required. Your code looks fine. I'm not sure if this issue is due to the partialview you return maybe being originally generated as a normal view which would automatically be using the _layout page which might cause issues like that. If you create a new basic partialview and return that instead does it cause the same problem?

Comment: No! But I tried return simple text and the same occurs. It's weird.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved the problem! In _Layout.cshtml there is a optional section to render in view called "scripts". What I did was just render the "script" section with:

```
@section scripts {
     <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
}

    ...

<div id="latestReviews"></div>

@Ajax.ActionLink("Click here to see the latest review", "LatestReviews", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions {
    UpdateTargetId =  "latestReviews",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "GET"
})
```